# Javascript: Iterate through for loop with setInterval synchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, setinterval

I'm working on a Simon Says program and I am running into issues with calling the computer's series of moves and displaying them on the screen.

I am attempting to use this aiMoves() function to iterate through the array and display each move by highlighting the appropriate color button. I am attempting to use setInterval so that the first button highlights, the program waits a second, then the next button highlights like so:

```
function aiTurns(randNum){
  for(var i = 0; i < aiMoves.length; i++) {
    if(aiMoves[i] === 1){
      //sound1();
      $('#green').addClass("active");
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('#green').removeClass("active");
      }, 500);
    }
    else if(aiMoves[i] === 2){
      //sound2();
      $('#red').addClass("active");
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('#red').removeClass("active");
      }, 500);
    }
    else if(aiMoves[i] === 3) {
      //sound3();
      $('#yellow').addClass("active");
      setTimeout(function(){
         $('#yellow').removeClass("active");
        }, 500);
      }
      else if(aiMoves[i] === 4){
      //sound4();
      $('#blue').addClass("active");
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('#blue').removeClass("active");
      }, 500);
    }
    level--;
    playerTurn = true;
  }
```

}

I called it like this:

```
var moves = function() {
aiTurns(randomNumber());
```

}

```
setInterval(moves, 2000);
}
```

The problem is setInterval is asynchronous and all iterations of the for loop within aiMoves() are called at the same time. How can I set this up so that the first element of the array executes, it pauses, then the next elements executes?

Here is the codepen for a better visualization:
https://codepen.io/nick_kinlen/pen/oGjMMr?editors=0010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `for` loop runs immediately until completion, you'll need a different way to run async code in series. Here's a simple abstraction that lets you loop over an array with a given delay in between each iteration:

```
function intervalForEach (array, iteratee, delay) {
  let current = 0

  let interval = setInterval(() => {
    if (current === array.length) {
      clearInterval(interval)
    } else {
      iteratee(array[current])
      current++
    }
  }, delay)
}
```

All of your conditional logic can go inside of the iteratee function, which just accepts the current item in the array. [Here's](https://codepen.io/djfdev/pen/JrwbKP) a working example.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different way to do it with async/await:

```js
const timeout = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

(async () => {
  var i = 1;
  while (true) {
    await timeout(1000);
    // iteration logic
    console.log(i++);
    // termination logic
    if(i > 10) {
      break;
    }
  }
  console.log("done");
})();
```

Here set interval is completely replaced with a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) using [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout), an [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await), and a [while loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while).